# How update session attribute after loading with JPA

Tags: session, servlets, jpa-2.0, session-variables

I have a problem with updating session attribute after loading some data with JPA.

I set/get session attribute:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);

User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
```

Somewhere in application i load list of `users` (contains same `user` as in session attribute) from database, modify and save. All will be well and I will be getting up to date information, but not if i will get from session attribute. 
I don't want request database for almost static information, but on the other hand i don't know how to update session attribute.

May be it is quite incorrect implementation to store the attributes of the session?

**UPDATE** 
how about this solution:

I have cache of sessions attributes

```
public static final HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> sessionAttributeMaps = new HashMap<>(); 

public static final HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>> sessionAttributeMapsForUpdate = new HashMap<>();
```

in `sessionAttributeMaps` i store session attributes (which i need to refresh later and keep in actual), using `HttpSessionAttributeListener`:

```
@WebListener
public class SessionAttributeListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener{

    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        String SessionId = event.getSession().getId();
        String attributeName = event.getName();        
        Object attributeValue = event.getValue();    

        if (attributeName.equalsIgnoreCase("user")) {
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = ServletUtil.sessionAttributeMaps.get(SessionId);
            if (hm==null) {
                hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                ServletUtil.sessionAttributeMaps.put(SessionId, hm);
            }
            hm.put("user", attributeValue);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

sessionAttributeMaps (for several created sessions):

[
[Session 1: [{"user" : user1}, {"customer" : customer1}]],

[Session 2: [{"user" : user1}, {"customer" : customer2}]],

[Session 3: [{"user" : user2}, {"customer" : customer1}]]
]

in `sessionAttributeMapsForUpdate` i store actual values of session attributes (when they are changed, i put in the map checking all sessions it is implemented in POJO entity).

```
public void fireChanges() {    
    for (Entry<String, HashMap<String, Object>> sessionAttributesMap : servlets.ServletUtil.sessionAttributeMaps.entrySet()) {
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : sessionAttributesMap.getValue().entrySet()) {
            if (this.equals(entry.getValue()) && this!=entry.getValue()) {
                entry.setValue(this);
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = ServletUtil.sessionAttributeMapsForUpdate.get(sessionAttributesMap.getKey());
                if (hm==null) {
                    hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    ServletUtil.sessionAttributeMapsForUpdate.put(sessionAttributesMap.getKey(), hm);
                }
                hm.put("user", this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If `user1` changed, i fill `sessionAttributeMapsForUpdate`:

[
[Session 1: [{"user" : user1}]],

[Session 2: [{"user" : user1}]]
]

in helper i get session attribute and check updates (with cleaning that is updated)

```
public static Object getSessionAttribute(String key) {

    Object value = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(key);

    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("user")) {
        if (!ServletUtil.sessionAttributeMapsForUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            HttpSession hs = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = ServletUtil.sessionAttributeMapsForUpdate.get(hs.getId());    
            if (hm!=null) {
                User u = (User) hm.get("user");
                if (u!=null) {
                    value = u;
                    removeSessionAttribute("user");
                    setSessionAttribute("user", value);

                    hm.remove("user");
                }
                if (hm.isEmpty()) {
                    ServletUtil.sessionAttributeMapsForUpdate.remove(hs.getId());
                }
            }
        }
    }

return value;
}
```

**WARNING**: `setSessionAttribute("user", value);` wihout `removeSessionAttribute("user");` not working because new `value` equals `value from session map` (but `!=`)

So, when i get session attribute with helper, i use actual value.

May be already there are solutions like my, but time-tested?

Comment: To update the session, you call `request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);` once again, with the updated user.

Comment: i have another problem. i update list of users and want update every user in all sessions. I tried to implement the updating scheme with the `HttpSessionAttributeListener` and the static list to store session and map of attributes. When i get value from session attribute i also compare with this atatic list, and change session attribute if values `equals` but `!=` . It work, but very difficult. Second problem - i can't refresh detached entity.

Comment: if this data is almost static, why not use a JPA L2 cache?  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching and https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_caching are good references.  An L2 cache would let you see changes made within the app, and invalidation strategies can be used to see changes made outside JPA.

Comment: @Chris I think it is the best solution too (wrapping the getters of attributes and getting values through JPA). I check, in fact, no hits to the database is done. So session attributes needed only as references to database. Thanks. No more questions.